# Bluetooth on Android: StartDiscovery not working. Not retrieve any resultes, BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection, broadcastreceiver, bluetooth-device-discovery

I am writing an application with bluetooth functionalities. I am able to set the bluetooth adapter, and fetch my own device information, but I could not use `startdiscovery` to discover bluetooth devices. When I start a scan, it does nothing, and about `broadcastReceiver` it like doesn't running.

I'm using `onClickListener` for discovery:

```
discoverBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        discover();
    }
});

private void discover() {
        if (!checkPermission()) {
            // Handle the case where permissions are not granted
            Log.d("DISCOVER BTN", "Permissions not granted");
            return;
        }

        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            // If discovery is already in progress, cancel it first
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.d("DISCOVER BTN", "Discovery canceled");
        }

        // Start device discovery
        Log.d("DISCOVER BTN", "Starting discovery");
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

        // Register the broadcast receiver for device discovery
        IntentFilter discoverIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverIntentFilter);
}
```

The `broadcaset` object:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            Log.d("ACTION", "ACTION_FOUND");
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                // object and its info from the Intent.
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                String deviceInfo = device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress();

                Log.d("BLUETOOTH DEVICE", deviceInfo);
                arrayList.add(deviceInfo);
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
                devicesLV.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            }
        }
};
```

It should log this message:

```
Log.d("BLUETOOTH DEVICE", deviceInfo);
```

but this is the last log:

```
2024-01-30 16:41:22.780 19749-19749 BluetoothAdapter        com.example.bluetoothapp2            I  startDiscovery
```

I have set bluetooth permissions in the android manifest file, and check if all permissions are granted.

It is supposed to show the list of discovered devices, but it log just shows `startDiscovery`. Please tell me how to use `startdiscovery` and `broadcastreceiver` properly to display the result.

This is the bluetooth permissions in the Android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

This is the checkPermission method:

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);

            return false;
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);

            return false;
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);

            return false;
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);

            return false;
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);

            return false;
        }

        return true;
}
```

Comment: Does startDiscovery() return true or false? Maybe the Bluetooth adapter is off.
Also, I would place registering the receiver before starting the discovery.

Comment: The Bluetooth adapter is on